# jQuery File Upload input type="file" do not attach a file

Tags: jquery, file, upload

I am trying to use jQuery File Upload, but when I click on fileupload input and select a file it gives my a message saying `file is not selected`.

Here is the code example:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jQueryFileUpload2/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jQueryFileUpload2/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jQueryFileUpload2/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">   
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery('#fileupload').fileupload({});
    });
</script>

<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="photo" value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missisg `);`at the end of the code:

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('#fileupload').fileupload({});
});
```

Comment: The rest of the code is fine ... maybe you have POST retrictions ... http://jsbin.com/berivo/edit?js,output